# Programmatically import configurable products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I use cron to import products in the database. Products are imported but the association between configurable products and simple products is not done correctly. The association is done every new product but at the end, only the last product imported remains. Please find the function I use below.

==EDIT==

This function is under community>Bmservices>Polaris>Model>Observer

It is called by a cron defined in config.xml that work. I am sure that the function is called as I am logging in it and the log is filling with the proper information.

==END OF EDIT==

I get the `$line` from csv.

```
private function _importProduct($line){
    $utf8bom = "\xef\xbb\xbf";
    $rayon = $this->_checkCategory($line[21]+2, $line[22]);
    $famille = $this->_checkCategory($line[23], $line[24], $rayon);
    $sousfamille = $this->_checkCategory($line[25], $line[26], $famille);
    $idManu = $this->_checkAttribute($line[5], $line[27], $this->_attributManufacturer);
    $idSais = $this->_checkAttribute($line[15], $line[28], $this->_attributSaison);
    $idColl = $this->_checkAttribute($line[16], $line[29], $this->_attributCollection);
    $idMati = $this->_checkAttribute($line[11], $line[35], $this->_attributMatiere);
    $idCoul = $this->_checkAttribute($line[3], $line[20], $this->_attributCouleur);
    $idTail = $this->_checkAttribute($line[4], $line[42], $this->_attributTaille, $line[43]);
    $idAttS = $this->_checkAttributeSet($line[49], $line[50]);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $sku = trim($line[0], $utf8bom);
    $sku = trim($sku, '"');
    $product->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    $id = $product->getId();
    if (empty($id)){
        Mage::log("nouveau produit avec le sku $sku");
        $product->setStoreId(1);
        $product->setSku($sku);
        $product->setAttributeSetId($idAttS);
        $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    }
    if ($line!=''){
        $product->setName($line[18]);
    } else {
        $product->setName($line[17]);
    }
    $product->setDescription($line[19]);
    $product->setCreatedAt($line[41]);
    $product->setShortDescription($line[19]);
    $product->setData('collecannee', $idColl);
    $product->setData('matiere', $idMati);
    $product->setData('manufacturer', $idManu);
    $product->setData('saison', $idSais);    
    $product->setMetaKeyword($line[22].','.$line[24].','.$line[26].','.$line[27].','.$line[28]);
    $product->setMetaTitle($line[18]);
    $product->setMetaDescription($line[19]);
    $product->setWeight(0);
    $product->setData('price',$line[47]);
    $product->setCategoryIds(array($rayon, $famille, $sousfamille));
    $product->setFinalPrice($line[47])        
        ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
        ->setMsrpEnabled(0) //enable MAP
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(4) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
        ->setMsrp($line[47]); //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
    if ($line[48]!=''){
        $product->setSpecialPrice($line[48]);
        $product->setSpecialFromDate('2014-08-01');
        $product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
        $product->setSpecialToDate('2014-08-30');
        $product->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true);
    } else {
        $product->setSpecialPrice(null);
    }
    $product->setTaxClassId(2);
    if ((!isset($this->_productConf))||($this->_productConf->getSku()!='C-'.$line[2])){
        if ((isset($this->_productConf))&&($this->_productConf->getSku()!='C-'.$line[2])){
            $this->_productConf->setConfigurableProductsData($this->_configurableProductsData);
            $this->_productConf->save();
        }
        $this->_productConf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $skuConf = 'C-'.$line[2];
        $this->_productConf->loadByAttribute('sku',$skuConf);
        $this->_configurableProductsData = array();
        $idConf = $this->_productConf->getId();
        if (empty($idConf)){
            Mage::log('Création d\'un produit configurable : '.$skuConf);
            $this->_productConf->setData($product->getData());
            $this->_productConf->setTypeId('configurable');
            $this->_productConf->setData('size', NULL);
            $this->_productConf->setData('color', NULL);
            $attribute_ids = array($this->_attributTaille, $this->_attributCouleur);
            $this->_productConf->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attribute_ids);
            $configurableAttributesData = $this->_productConf->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
            $this->_productConf->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
            $this->_productConf->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
            $StockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
            $StockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
            $StockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
            $StockData['use_config_min_qty'] = 0;
            $this->_productConf->setStockData($StockData);
            $this->_productConf->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
            $this->_productConf->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            $this->_productConf->setSku($skuConf);
            $this->_productConf->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        }
    }
    $StockData['qty'] = floatval($line[46]);
    $StockData['is_in_stock'] = ($StockData['qty']>0) ? 1 : 0;
    $StockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
    $StockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
    $StockData['use_config_min_qty'] = 0;
    $product->setStockData($StockData);
    $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
    $product->setData('size', $idTail);
    $product->setData('color', $idCoul);
    Mage::log("sauvegarde du produit");
    $product->validate();
    $product->save();

    /**
     * mise à jour du prix et de la classe de taxe
     */
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()),
        array(121 => 2, 75 => $line[47]),
        0
    );

    /**
     * gestion du stock
     */
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
    $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
    $stock = array();

    if (!$stockItemId) {
        $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
        $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
    } else {
        $stock = $stockItem->getData();
    }

    foreach($StockData as $field => $value) {
        $stockItem->setData($field, $value?$value:0);
    }
    $stockItem->save();
    $this->_configurableProductsData[$product->getId()] = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => $line[20], //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => $this->_attributCouleur, //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => $idCoul, //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => $line[47] //value for the pricing
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'label' => $line[42], //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => $this->_attributTaille, //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => $idTail, //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => $line[47] //value for the pricing
        )
    );
}
```

Is there something I miss.

Comment: Where did you write this function? Please, name folder and file.

Comment: I added the information you needed by editing the question. I can provide more information if need be. Moreover, when I try reindexing, it does not work (nothing in the flat table even if it is active) exept if I edit the product in the admin.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit, Christophe. I am trying to solve your issue but it seems it is not related to core Magento 1.9. Is this code part of an extension, isn't it?

Comment: It is a part of an extension. I am trying to import products configurable from a remote ERP. Thanks to you for helping me. I came to think that it comes from some attribute not populated but cannot get which. I will edit the function with what I have now but it does not work better.

Comment: You are welcome. I am trying to reproduce the error in order to be able to help you. To do so, I need to know the name of the extension. Is this possible?

Comment: I am writting the extension as nothing existed for that erp. But You made me think that I did not try to package the extension and to try it on a fresh installation of magento.

Comment: Sorry pablo for inconvenience but I found my mistake. Thanks a lot for the time you took to review my code. I hope I will be able to help you back one day !

Comment: I am really glad you found the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake and I could not believe it got me stuck for more than a week. In case somebody encounter the same issue, the answer lies in the website ids. I did not affect any so the product did not exist in any store so it was affected but not visible on the product page. I can not explain why I had it on admin and in the database but now everything is ok.